# How many programming languages do you use at one time?

Tags: programming-languages

During a normal work-day, tackling a variety of tasks, there's the potential for several programming languages to be used.

There's application work, with C#, VB.NET, C++, Java, Fortran, then there's database work with involves SQL, and then there's maintenance work involving languages like Python, Perl, PHP, or even bash scripts and similar.

Which programming languages do you use, for which task, and why?

Since this is a poll-type question, please state your main line of work, be it developing web applications or desktop applications, systems maintenance, systems administration, etc.

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: I'm not interested in a contest to who is the best either.  I'm interested in whether or not it is best to focus your career on a language or two or just work on everything that comes to you.

Comment: You are missing the second part of that quote: "Jack of all trades, master of none, though ofttimes better than master of one"

Comment: Really, SchwartzE? How do you propose to figure that out based on the answers to this question?

Comment: I'd vote to reopen if it was community wiki, and asked in a more objective voice (how many active programming languages is optimal for x type of application or something similar, rather than the vague "how many do you use," "what do you develop?"

Comment: I note that SO makes the question 67% mine now, I didn't intend to "own" the question in that way, I just wanted to edit it to make it easier to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make maintenance easier you want to keep the number of different programing languages to a minimum.
For me the answer is that I use 2-3 in an average project.
Currently I use three languages at work:
1. C++ for needed low level programing.
2. C# for application level programing.
3. VB.NET for some VB related functionality and code examples shipped with the application.

I've used C# and C++ in many projects and found that it covers most of the project's needs.

Answer (score 2):

I am a web application developer, in the last week I've done the following:

- Created Stored Procedures using **T-SQL** for SQL Server
- Debugged **Perl** Script that created databases
- Written **C#** Web-service code
- Written **JavaScript** (Both with and without **JQuery**)
- Debugged **CSS** and **HTML** issues in IE6 and IE7

On my personal time, I've also used the **ASP.NET MVC** platform and C# to write a customized Content Management System.

Comment: sans the perl scripting these are my languages exactly but add IE8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera to the list of browsers we test against

Comment: Professionally, we only test against IE6 and IE7 (although firefox is on the roadmap). This is because our clients are corporations, which primarily use IE6 (and to a lesser extent, IE7). On a personal level, I test to Firefox first, and IE second.

Answer (score 1):

Our shop focuses almost exclusively on VB.NET, but you could also say that I have to work with VB and JavaScript since I do a lot of ASP.NET development.

SQL if you want to count that as a programming language as well.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? It is the lingua franca of Databases.

Comment: @Gortok: it's not even Turing-complete! (but I guess you could still consider a programming language...)

Comment: SQL itself doesn't feel like a programming language. TSQL on the other hand...

Comment: I personally consider it a programming language, just not sure about the rest of the community.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you are doing.

For a web developer, it would be *very* common to work with a client-side and a server-side language every day, such as javascript and Java.

Edit: you would use HTML and possibly XML, but these are markup languages. I'm honestly not sure what CSS would be considered, but yes, you use that also.

Comment: Just one of each? += HTML, SQL, XML, CSS...

Comment: @annakata: none of those are real programming languages(SQL maybe but is not turing complete)

Answer (score 1):

For web development:

PHP-JS-SQL-{HTML}-{CSS}

Lets count this as... 3.5 languages?

Comment: Same here, and sometimes I write a small C# tool to help do some work.

Comment: I would count HTML, CSS, and JS as 1 language. Its hard to make a modern site without all 3. Also, sql is not turing complete so it should also not count as a full language.

Comment: Unkown, but JS is (as far as I know) turing complete. So your reasoning is flawed :P

Comment: Just got back from learning what 'turing complete' means! :)

Answer (score 1):

Neverminding the other languages I deal with, the first number I thought of was 5, with the list having only one entry: "Javascript"... damn browsers. :)

I suppose "optimal" is measured by the fewest which allow you to create a solution which is reasonably maintainable down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Probably 1/2 a day mainly switching between Ruby / plpgsql (if that counts?) and BASH.

Though sometimes I may have to debug some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The fewer programming languages I'm dealing with at any given moment in time, the fewer times I find myself making really dumb syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

On a given day I try to limit it to 2 or 3, but in a given week it may be 5 or 6.

Answer (score 0):

On a good day, one. On a bad day it's 6-7. I find myself looking up simple syntax a lot more when I'm using many at one time.

Answer (score 0):

I work as a web developer so on any given day I will be writing/debugging HTML, CSS, Javascript and .Net apps.  In my free time I enjoy c++ and c#.  I have also been contracted to port a vb app to c# so its going to get interesting...

If I were learning a new language, I would definitely recommend C++ and C#, interesting, powerful and if you are good in c++ you can probably work in anything...

Answer (score 0):

I work for a creative studio and do some freelance work. I am often switching between the following:

- **Actionscript 2**  (*mainly on old legacy projects*)
- **Actionscript 3**  (*most of my day job projects*)
- **javascript**  (*personal projects/user scripts*)
- **C#**  (*getting a few projects now for WPF*)
- **Processing**  (*quick sketches of ideas/personal projects*)

Also some markup and other "languages":

- **HTML/CSS**
- **XAML**
- **XML** (*didn't want to put this, but I use it a lot*)
- **regex** (*does this count?*)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly C#, followed by XSLT/XPath, T-SQL, Javascript, VB.NET when it's forced on me, Power Shell, VBA,  and HTML and CSS if you're counting those.  So that's about 6-9.

Answer (score 0):

I use 3 languages every days and 6 or so every weeks.

BUT I really know only 2, maybe 3 of them. When I code using the others, I'm googling every 5 minutes !

(Hey, but it works ! :)

- Every day or so : VB.NET, C#, SQL/T-SQL.
- Every week : HTML, XML, C,
  JavaScript.
- Every other weeks : Make files, batch
  files.
- Really known languages : C, C#,
  VB.NET.

Cool question ^^

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET and Javascript at work, with a healthy dose of CSS.

VB.NET, VB6, C++, Javascript, PHP, C#, 65816 ASM, and a bunch of smaller languages at home, for whatever little project I'm working on at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fortunate to be working with just one language for the past year: C++/CLI. And each day I'm surprised by how little of it I actually know.